# Doctrine2 random query

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to fetch 2 rows from my database randomly with doctrine2, and I can't manage to do it. I figured out that there is no possibility to do it easily with RAND(), but then which is the best solution?

And from the table I want to select rows which are for example for sale, I mark it with 1 in is_sale, so because of this I couldn't do it with simple offset.

Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243040/how-to-fetch-random-row-via-doctrine2-querybuilder

Answer (score 0):

When asking this question on Twitter just now, I got pointed to [this post about selecting random records](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/). This guy makes a very valid point on the performance of using RAND(). I guess it's better to generate the random id's in the application, then select those records using Doctrine.